# How can I echo a single element of this object?

Tags: php, google-sheets

I'm trying to use this [php library](https://github.com/emilianozublena/sheetsu-php) along with [Sheetsu](http://sheetsu.com) to pull single bits of data from a Google spreadsheet for output on a web page. My php skills are minimal and spotty, I'm afraid, and so I'm missing a final crucial component.

When I set up a test file and run my query, the code dumps everything into a $collection object. If I output `print_r($collection);` I get this:

```
Sheetsu\Collection Object (
    [models:Sheetsu\Collection:private] => Array (
        [0] => Sheetsu\Model Object (
             [id] => 2.05.1
             [title] => The Mead of Poetry
             [answer] => Kvasir was created from the spit of the Aesir and Vanir. He was very wise. 
        )
    )
)
```

My data's there, everything's working as expected, but I've never seen a structure like that before.

How can I just echo, say, just the [answer] value? I'm not sure what syntax to use to drill into that.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `echo $collection->models[0]->answer;`

Comment: Seems like that kicks out this: _PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Sheetsu\Collection::$models in /home/ferrellw/public_html/sheetsutest/sheetsu.php on line 16_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$collection->get(0)
```

or

```
$collection->getFirst()
```

or

```
$collection->getAll()[0]
```

etc.

models is a private property, you can't access it directly

so to access answer it would be something like

```
$collection->get(0)->answer
```

Comment: `$collection->get(0)->answer` did the trick! I see how that works, but wow—I don't know how long it would have been before I stumbled across that one myself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try echo $collection[0]->answer;

Comment: Thanks—this syntax gives me the same error as above, I'm afraid.